# MongoDB Connection Error

Tags: mongodb

After Successful installation of mongodb Server on Ubuntu 14.04.01, when i changed default bind address that is 127.0.0.1 to my local LAN ip. monogoDB shows connection error

Comment: Please try to check whether any other software is running behind and blocking the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just running the `mongo` shell command with no arguments it will default to connect to the localhost (which resolves to `127.0.0.1` usually). Since you have just removed that from the bind setting it will fail (`mongod` is now listening only on the LAN IP).

Hence you have to explicitly specify the LAN IP when you invoke the `mongo` shell to ensure you connect to the bound address.  In my case, my LAN IP is `192.168.2.40` so I can connect on that address like so:

```
mongo 192.168.2.40
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.6
connecting to: 192.168.2.40:27017/test
>
```

For reference you run the shell command without arguments it is basically the equivalent of this:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1:27017
```

You can bind to the LAN IP and the loopback also either by removing the bind setting entirely (will listen on all interfaces) or by adding 127.0.0.1 after the LAN IP (comma seperated).